# Slow PC after installing new GPU

Tags: performance, gpu

A few days ago I installed my new GT 610 (I know you cant game on it)
but my pc slowed down drasticly. For example it takes about 3 minutes to open chrome, about 40 seconds to load the menu when right clicking on the desktop. the screen sometimes flickers and goes into what looks like safe mode. I checked the load on my GPU with GPU-Z but it inly said about 1% load in idle and about 8% when using chrome.

PC Specs:

Intel Core 2 Duo  E7500 @ 2.93Ghz CPU
GT 610 GPU
2GB DDR2 667Mhz RAM
MSI G31TM-P35 Motherboard
WD Caviar Blue 250GB & 320GB HDD
350W PSU

Comment: Have you installed the latest drivers?  Are there any errors in the Device Manager?

Comment: Newest drivers. No errors in Device Manager

Answer (score 0):

update all your drivers. check if windows update is running in the background.
if all your drivers are up to date and windows update is not running in the background, check your hard disk for errors using chkdsk and run a file benchmark using hdtune. if your hard disk is way slower than 80MB per second there is a problem, and you need to replace your **Hard Drive** and install a new operating system on the new hard drive etc.

Comment: OK Thanks, I will do what you said when I get home. I did get all the parts for the PC from 3 old PC's, so I wouldnt be suprised if the hard drive was dying.

Comment: BTW what has the new GPU have to do with the Hard Drive. The PC was fine before installing the new GPU.

Comment: @CheapoPC if you followed the steps above, run a file benchmark using hdtune and then we can discuss

Comment: @CheapoPC there is something wrong with your hard disk. It's way slower than usual. also you have 2 hard drives. which one is 14 MBps ?

Comment: no no no nvm.   I am currently running the right bench and the avarge is 126MB/sec.

Comment: @Cheapo PC are you using the power saving mode?

Comment: no havent even heard of that

Comment: and I disabled windows ipdate since it was eating like a gig of ram

Comment: but my hdd is fine, its not the problem. since 120mbps doesent sound like a prob to me

Comment: What else could be the problem :/